# List all files in my S3 bucket on my website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a AWS S3 bucket with lots of images split in separate folders. I need to list all those images on my website using javascript and be able to upload a new image to the S3 bucket directly from my website. What is the best possible way to do it in javascript ?

Comment: This question asked is way beyond the title"list files", it involve publishing bucket to website, s3 access control.

Comment: what is the language of the back end? nodeJS?

Comment: AWS documentation for JavaScript API: [Calling the listObjects operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property)

Answer (score -3):

Sorry mate, no offense meant here. Why don't you try to read the manual or read the official documentation?

Here it is, a Javascript example, from Amazon, to list the S3 objects in a bucket

https://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1713

I hope this helps